# Update Widget on Update Status with ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, flutter-change-notifier

I am new to Flutter and I am trying to make the UI refresh the page whenever there's an action triggered by the user, e.g. on button pressed to update this order item status. I have the following codes for my widget with ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
    body: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: Provider.of<OrderItemModel>(context, listen: false),
        child: Consumer<OrderItemModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {...some widgets...}
```

I have a function named updateStatus().

```
  void updateStatus(orderItem, status) {
    Provider.of<OrderItemModel>(context, listen: false)
        .updateOrderStatus(orderItem, status, '');
  }
```

However, I couldn't find a way to update the UI. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => OrderItemModel(),
  child: Consumer<OrderItemModel>(builder: (context, model, child) {...some widgets...}
```

`updateStatus` needs to be defined in a Widget class further down the widget tree in order for `Provider.of` to work. If it isn't, I suggest calling `model.updateOrderStatus` directly from the `onPressed` callback.